# exposing a function with 2D slice as a parameter in a c-shared library (to be used in Java via JNA and C)

Tags: go, shared-libraries

I am trying to write a simple matrix operations API using `go` and expose the APIs as a shared library. This shared library will be used from Java(using JNA) and from C.
The documentation is very sparse about using any data type beyond simple `int` or `string` as function parameters.
My requirement is to expose functions with 1 or more 2D slices as parameters AND also as return types. I am not able to figure out if such a thing is supported.
Is this possible? Are there any examples for this?

Answer (score -1):

I think the key point is to have a look to the c bindings of `slice,string and int` generated by `go build` tool. I not tried 2D slice, but it should no different to 1D slice with `unsafe` pointer converter, maybe just be one more time allocation and convertion.

I'm not sure it's the best way, but here's the example for 1D slice:

the go part:

```
import "C"
//export CFoo
func CFoo(content []byte) string{
    var ret []byte
    //blablabla to get ret
    cbuf := unsafe.Pointer(C.malloc(C.size_t(len(ret))))
    C.memcpy(cbuf, unsafe.Pointer(&ret[0]), C.size_t(len(ret)))
    var finalString string
    hdr := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&finalString))
    hdr.Data = uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(cbuf))
    hdr.Len = len(ret)
    return finalString
}
```

compile with `-buildmode=c-shared`, to get `libmygo.so`.

I not know JNA, expecting it like JNI. the JNI part as well as pure C part:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef signed char GoInt8;
typedef unsigned char GoUint8;
typedef short GoInt16;
typedef unsigned short GoUint16;
typedef int GoInt32;
typedef unsigned int GoUint32;
typedef long long GoInt64;
typedef unsigned long long GoUint64;
typedef GoInt32 GoInt;
typedef GoUint32 GoUint;
typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ GoUintptr;
typedef float GoFloat32;
typedef double GoFloat64;
typedef float _Complex GoComplex64;
typedef double _Complex GoComplex128;

typedef struct { const char *p; GoInt n; } GoString;
typedef void *GoMap;
typedef void *GoChan;
typedef struct { void *t; void *v; } GoInterface;
typedef struct { void *data; GoInt len; GoInt cap; } GoSlice;

JNIEXPORT JNICALL jbyteArray Java_com_mynextev_infotainment_app_myev_Native_foo(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj,jbyteArray content){
    JNIEnv ienv = *env;

    void * Ccontent = ienv->GetByteArrayElements(env, content, 0); 
    int Lcontent = ienv->GetArrayLength(env, content);
    GoSlice Gcontent = {Ccontent, Lcontent, Lcontent};
    if(!gret.n){
        printf("jni CDoAESEnc");
        return NULL;
    }
    jbyteArray ret = ienv->NewByteArray(env, gret.n);
    ienv->SetByteArrayRegion(env, ret, 0, gret.n, gret.p);
    free((void*)gret.p);
    ienv->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, content, Ccontent, JNI_ABORT);
    return ret;
}
```

build it with `libmygo.so`.

finally you get two `so` files. one for C which can be used standalone; one for Java which must be used with `libmygo.so` together.